# Finding Width of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, bjt, power-electronics

[image: Question]

We are struggling with part iv of the question above where we have to find the width of both MOSFETS. As you can see from our working out, we have found a width of 2 meters for the nMOS, which we know is way too big.
Is there something wrong with our working or are we going about working it out completely the wrong way?

\$First \space find \space I_b:\$

\$\beta_f = \frac{I_c}{I_b} \approx \frac{I_e}{I_b}\$

\$Rearrange\space to\space find \space I_{b}\$

\$I_b = \frac{I_e}{\beta_f} = \frac{3mA}{200} = 1.5 \times 10^{-5}A\$

\$I_d \space (of \space MOSFET)= I_b\space (of \space BJT)\$

\$Substitute\space I_d\space into:\$

\$g_m = \frac{I_d}{V_{Th}} = \frac{1.5\times 10^{-5}}{25mV} = 6 \times 10^{-4} \$

\$Now\space using:\$

\$g_m = \frac{2I_d}{V_{gs} - V_t}\$

\$Rearrange\space to\space find \space V_{gs}\$

\$V_{gs} = \frac{2I_d + g_mV_t}{g_m} = \frac{(2 \times 1.5 \times 10^{-5}) + (6 \times 10^{-4} \times 0.8)}{6 \times 10^{-4}} = 0.85 \$

\$Now\space using:\$

\$I_d = \frac{K'}{2}\frac{W}{L}(V_{gs} - V_t)^2\$

\$Rearrange\space to\space find \space W\$

\$nMOS \space W = \frac{2I_dL}{K'(V_{gs} - V_T)^2} = \frac{(2 \times 1.5 \times 10^{-5}) \times 5 \times 10^{-6}}{3 \times 10^{-8} \times (0.95 - 0.8)^2} = 2\$

\$pMOS \space W = \frac{2I_dL}{K'(V_{gs} - V_T)^2} = \frac{(2 \times 1.5 \times 10^{-5}) \times 5 \times 10^{-6}}{1 \times 10^{-6} \times (0.95 - 0.8)^2} = 0.06\$

[image: Working Out]

Comment: 2 meters seems a bit large for a mosfet.

Comment: Could you maybe transcribe the work into the question? Not everyone can reliably read even the cleanest handwriting, and the pictures being sideways certainly doesn't help.

Comment: Added a rough transcription

Comment: Neat cropping! How come we have had three or four channel width questions within one week? Is it that time of the year in some class?

Comment: The site does support latex, please format your question or at least put the pictures right side up.

Comment: added latex and cropped the images better

Comment: I think the MU*Cox of the Nch is way low, unless these are organic FETS. Are they?

Comment: As far as I know they're just standard FETS. We've barely covered organic so I doubt they would be.